# setting min/max length in random.shuffle output?

Tags: python, random

so in order to work on my newly learned python i wrote a small tool to random passwords.

eventually i get to a list with, lets say 15 strings. i ask wrote it so that the user can input how many passwords he wants to get, and how long. - instead of that i want to ask him what the min and max len, not a set len, and get that full range in my results.

this is what i have so far:

```
items = ['5', '4', 'Y', 'T', 'R', 'E', 'h', 'g', 'f', 'd', '7', '1', '9', 'z', 'q', 'x']

x=int(raw_input("how many passwords would you like?:"))
z=int(raw_input("how long would you like the password to be?:"))

print("the list of possible passwords you received is:")
for i in range (x):
    random.shuffle(items)
```

and an output would be something like:

```
TR1Eg47f9
5gRf9q7Ed
hxfE5gR4d
hE14x9Tz7
```

thank you.

Comment: Your requirements are a bit under-specified. If the user wants ten passwords with min length 5 and max length 7, how many passwords of length 5 should be generated? How many of length 6? And how many of length 7? Should these be generated in some particular order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [random.sample](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) you can get a specific amount of items from the list. You could do something like this:

```py
from random import sample
print(''.join(sample(items, x)))
```

The **problem** with this, is that `x` cannot be greater than the items length. You could do some fix before, repeating the items in the list like this:

```
while len(items) < x:
    items += items
```

Comment: could i just insert the while len (items) part somewhere in my code? or does it not work with my shuffle and i have to go sample?

Comment: shuffle will modify the items order in the list, while sample will give you a new list with the amount of items specified by `x`. The `while len(items) < x` part should be executed when you know how long you want your password to be.